# Dockerfile COPY / ADD fails for file in build context

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The dockerfile COPY command is failing despite the source file existing in the build context.

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.4.1, build 5bc2ff8/1.4.1
```

Dockerfile:

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM centos
COPY "test", "/"
```

Directory contents:

```
$ ls -Al
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nottingham nottingham 29 Apr  1 14:21 Dockerfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nottingham nottingham  0 Apr  1 14:26 test
```

Build output:

```
$ docker build  -t nottingham/test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.56 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon
Step 0 : FROM centos
 ---> 88f9454e60dd
Step 1 : COPY "test", "/"
INFO[0000] "test",: no such file or directory
```

Similar errors occur when using the COPY [src, dest] form or the ADD command. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the comma and quotes. Use:

```
FROM centos
COPY test /
```